Use Tom-Select inside Leaflet Control
I'm trying to use TomSelect inside of a Leaflet control layer. Displaying it works as expected, but I'm not able to select anything.
It seems like the click event is not getting through to the TomSelect element.
This also happens with scrolling inside the options of the TomSelect, but I was able to get this working with L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation. Unfortunately, L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation and/or L.DomEvent.on(el, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation) did not yield the same result for the click event.
I prepared a jsfiddle to showcase the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/7kbzL93u/53/
Can I somehow get the selecting to work?
